# AngularJS template binding key/value

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible in a AngularJS ng-model directive to set the key of an object and the value in the other.  For example:

```
   {
        1234: "blue"
   }
```

and then my template looks like:

```
  <select ng-model="obj[?]">
       <option value="1234">Panda</option>
       <option value="1235">Moose</option>
  </select>

  <select ng-model="obj[?]">
       <option value="blue">Blue</option>
       <option value="red">Red</option>
  </select>
```

essentially I want to set the key as the first select and the value from the second select of that key.  I know its possible with some basic obj manipulation but wondering if there was a better way through angular magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use option values in Angular. I would use these arrays of objects in this case

```
<select ng-model="choices[0].key1">
   <option>Panda</option>
   <option>Moose</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="choices[0].key2">
   <option>Blue</option>
   <option>Red</option>
</select>

$scope.choices = [{
    key1 : "Panda",
    key2 : "Blue"
},{
    key1 : "Moose",
    key2 : "Red"
}];
```